# Postgres Connection refused when connecting remotely from a specific IP

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

### Issue

postgres doesn't appear to let me connect via the command line f my IP address is stated, regardless of what updates I try to make to my pg_hba.conf` file. If I run my user with address set to anywhere then it works without a problem.

### Setup

- I'm running my postgres database off of a google vm.
- I have enabled a firewall whitelist for incoming traffic from my Ip address on tcp port 5432.
- I set up the same thing when testing my mariadb database and I can connect to that without issue, so there shouldn't be an issue with my server firewall.

### Error Message

> ```
> user@Work-Station-A:~$ psql -U user -h <google vm public IP> -p 5432 cheese
> psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>         Is the server running on host "<google vm public IP>" and accepting
>         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

### /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf

> ```
> local   all             postgres                                peer
> # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
> host    all             user           <my ip address>         md5
> # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
> local   all             all                                     peer
> # IPv4 local connections:
> host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
> # IPv6 local connections:
> host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
> ```

### /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf

> ```
> listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
> port = 5432
> ssl = on
> ```

### What I noticed

When I remove the line for my 'user' ip connection in the `pg_hba.conf` file, I can see that the port listens:

> ```
> user@work-server:~$ ss -nlt | grep 5432
> LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:5432             0.0.0.0:*
> LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:5432                [::]:*
> ```

But if I put the line back in, nothing is returned when I check for listening ports on 5432. If I run my 
pg_hba.conf` to be

> `host    all             user             0.0.0.0/0               md5`

then It will listen and I can connect to my database without issue. For some reason my ip address seems to cause the ports to close, but I haven't been able to work out why. Can someone confirm if there is something I am doing wrong or need to amend to resolve this as I don't want my database to be accessible from anywhere?

Comment: Check your logs after you added your address to pg_hba.conf file and restart your Postgresql process. If no process is listening port 5432 your postgres didn't start right.

Comment: @ex4 I can confirm I'm restarting the postgres each time I amend the file with `sudo service postgresql restart`. Are you able to confirm how I can check the logs and what I should be looking for? Sorry if that's a basic question, I'm pretty new to setting up my own sql databases

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to leave the database open to all IPs and filter on the server by IPTABLES creating an access rule only for your Public IP or the IPs you need

Something like this should be the instruction:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 5432 --source <google vm public IP>
```

You can read a bit of IPTABLES in the following [LINK](https://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/)